Error: in `sync`: revision android-4.14-q in kernel/common not found
Some years ago I managed to emulate Android 10 on my Jetson Nano. It was a special version of Android,prepared by antmicro and the github is located here :
https://github.com/antmicro/kvm-aosp-jetson-nano
I would like to compile it again and try to emulate it on my Jetson Nano again and on my Intel PC + Ubuntu 24.04 x64 bit.
I followed the tutorial again and I've been able to create the Android img files below without problems :
out/target/product/generic_arm64/vendor.img

out/target/product/generic_arm64/system.img

out/target/product/generic_arm64/userdata.img

out/target/product/generic_arm64/ramdisk.img

Now I need the kernel,so I tried to fetch the kernel sources to compile it. Unfortunately the github is old and some links are broken.
I want to ask your help to fix the broken link as better as possible :
root@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:/mnt/sdl1/aosp_kernel# repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b q-common-android-4.14

Downloading Repo source from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo

repo has been initialized in /mnt/sdl1/aosp_kernel

root@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:/mnt/sdl1/aosp_kernel# repo sync

Fetching: 0% (0/8) 0:07 | 2 jobs | 0:05 kernel/build @ buildRicezione degli oggetti: 84% (14706/17

Fetching: 0% (0/8) 0:07 | 2 jobs | 0:06 kernel/build @ buildRicezione degli oggetti: 85% (14881/17

Ricezione degli oggetti: 100% (17506/17506), 12.23 MiB | 46.57 MiB/s, fatto.

Risoluzione dei delta: 100% (8869/8869), fatto.

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 9:11 | 1 job | 9:01 kernel/common @ commonRicezione degli oggetti: 0% (1/12468

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 9:12 | 1 job | 9:02 kernel/common @ commonRicezione degli oggetti: 0% (80382/1

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 9:12 | 1 job | 9:03 kernel/common @ commonRicezione degli oggetti: 1% (124682/

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 9:13 | 1 job | 9:03 kernel/common @ commonRicezione degli oggetti: 1% (163592/

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 9:14 | 1 job | 9:04 kernel/common @ commonRicezione degli oggetti: 1% (245123/

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 9:15 | 1 job | 9:05 kernel/common @ commonRicezione degli oggetti: 2% (333147/

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 9:15 | 1 job | 9:06 kernel/common @ commonRicezione degli oggetti: 3% (374044/

.....

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 12:06 | 1 job | 11:57 kernel/common @ commonRisoluzione dei delta: 98% (1023355

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 12:07 | 1 job | 11:58 kernel/common @ commonRisoluzione dei delta: 99% (1028207

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 12:08 | 1 job | 11:59 kernel/common @ commonRisoluzione dei delta: 100% (1034277

Risoluzione dei delta: 100% (10342775/10342775), fatto.

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 13:44 | 1 job | 13:34 kernel/common @ common

fatal: can't find remote refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common:

kernel/common: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying

error: Cannot fetch kernel/common from https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 13:45 | 1 job | 0:01 kernel/tests @ kernel/tests

Ricezione degli oggetti:

Ricezione degli oggetti: 100% (11797/11797), 4.91 MiB | 48.34 MiB/s, fatto.

Risoluzione dei delta: 100% (2123/2123), fatto.

Fetching: 100% (8/8), done in 18m26.961s

Fetching: 0% (0/1) 0:04 | 1 job | 0:04 kernel/common @ common

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common:

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

error: Cannot fetch kernel/common from https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common

Fetching: 100% (1/1), done in 5.046s

error: Cannot checkout kernel/common: ManifestInvalidRevisionError: revision android-4.14-q in kernel/common not found

error: in \sync`: revision android-4.14-q in kernel/common not found`

root@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:/mnt/sdl1/aosp_kernel# repo sync

Fetching: 0% (0/8) 0:09 | 2 jobs | 0:07 kernel/common @ common

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common:

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

error: Cannot fetch kernel/common from https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common

Fetching: 100% (8/8), done in 12.927s

Fetching: 0% (0/1) 0:04 | 1 job | 0:04 kernel/common @ common

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common:

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

error: Cannot fetch kernel/common from https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common

Fetching: 100% (1/1), done in 5.008s

error: Cannot checkout kernel/common: ManifestInvalidRevisionError: revision android-4.14-q in kernel/common not found

error: in \sync`: revision android-4.14-q in kernel/common not found`

root@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:/mnt/sdl1/aosp_kernel# repo sync

Fetching: 50% (4/8) 0:04 | 1 job | 0:03 kernel/common @ common

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common:

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

error: Cannot fetch kernel/common from https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common

Fetching: 100% (8/8), done in 5.696s

Fetching: 0% (0/1) 0:04 | 1 job | 0:04 kernel/common @ common

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common:

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

kernel/common: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying

fatal: impossibile trovare il riferimento remoto refs/heads/android-4.14-q

error: Cannot fetch kernel/common from https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common

Fetching: 100% (1/1), done in 4.930s

error: Cannot checkout kernel/common: ManifestInvalidRevisionError: revision android-4.14-q in kernel/common not found

error: in \sync`: revision android-4.14-q in kernel/common not found

I expect that it can checkout kernel/common: ManifestInvalidRevisionError: revision android-4.14-q or a similar version compatible with the rest of the compiled Android
